# How to write a Python loop based on unique column responses to kick off machine learning model

Tags: python, loops, machine-learning, data-science

First time posting on here so please ignore my poor formatting attempts. I need help determining the best way to pass a unique list of user IDs and their associated values through my ML algorithm, and then append each users' results to a new df together.

Situation: I have a large dataset that contains a column for user IDs, timestamps, and actions taken. The dataset contains the records of what every user has done over time logging into a building. For example, Daniel: 8:15a enter building, Daniel: 5:00p exit building, Daniel: 10:30p enter building again. The simple screenshot image I embedded will show you how each user will get a row whenever they have a new log attempt. I have the behavior of every user in 1 dataset. My goal is to run an anomaly detection algorithm that looks at the behavior of each person independently to see if their card access is being used suspiciously. I don't need help with the algo or the ML part, but rather the best way to pass my list of users into the model in a systematic way.

The list of users is dynamic and can change depending on when the search is ran to pull the data of building access. Writing something such as `df_unique = df['UserID'].unique()` will create the list unique users. How would I write the loop to take each user, run a set of static pre-processing helper functions (like creating a new column based on some criteria), pass the new df of "Daniel" into my model, and then return my results to a new df?

The output goal would be to have a new df that is the same length as the original, but with a new column that returns my result from the algo. I've done that using the below, but I can't figure out how to loop it with the above requirements included:

```
df_clean['result'] = df_clean.clust.map({-1:'Anomaly', 1:'Normal'})
```

[image: Example Dataset]

Any thoughts?!

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that I did understand what you wanted, I wrote the following code:

- The first part (`model_doing_stuff`) and the one in which I construct the variable `dicts`, are used to construct a function to mock the model behavior and to create an example dataframe (from your example data) respectively
- In the core part of the code, I am iterating through the names obtained by the unique method of df.
- for each name I am selecting the sub-dataframe containing the related info
- for the values associated to a specific name I "run" the model and I return the results
- the results are added as column in the slice-copy of the original dataframe
- at the end of the for loop all the the partial dataframes are concatenated to form your desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import random

# mocked model 
def model_doing_stuff(values):
    return [random() for el in values]

# dataframe construction
users = ["Daniel", "Steve", "Wendy", "Daniel", "Daniel"]
times = ["8:15am", "9.00am", "8.45am", "5.00pm", "10.30pm"]
actions = ["Enter Building", "Enter Building", "Enter Building", "Leave Building", "Enter Building"]
dicts = [{"User ID":name, "Time ": time , "Action": action} for name, time, action in zip(users, times, actions)]
df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
print(df)

# construction of result dataframe
dfs = []
for name in df["User ID"].unique():
    curr_df = df[df["User ID"] == name]
    result = model_doing_stuff(curr_df["Action"])
    curr_df["results"] = result
    print(curr_df)
    dfs.append(curr_df)
    
result_df = pd.concat(dfs)
print(result_df)
```

```
User ID    Time           Action   results
0  Daniel   8:15am  Enter Building  0.191015
3  Daniel   5.00pm  Leave Building  0.195548
4  Daniel  10.30pm  Enter Building  0.213284
1   Steve   9.00am  Enter Building  0.643041
2   Wendy   8.45am  Enter Building  0.762887
```